# Typedef Struct pointer not recognized

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

I have a structure definition in file `platform.h`:

```
typedef struct {
    VL53L0X_DevData_t Data;
    uint8_t   I2cDevAddr;  
    uint8_t   comms_type;  
    uint16_t  comms_speed_khz;
    uint16_t  devID;
    I2C_HandleTypeDef * i2c_handle;
} VL53L0X_Dev_t;
```

And a typedef to a pointer like this in the same file:

```
typedef VL53L0X_Dev_t* VL53L0X_DEV;
```

In another file, a reference to `VL53L0X_DEV` is failing with `error: unknown type name 'VL53L0X_DEV'`
I have included `platform.h` in this other file. What is wrong with this?

**EDIT**

I'm stuck with using this code (a lot of it) supplied by a vendor and hence there isn't much scope for doing away with the pointer typedef or for providing an MCVE example. Here's the relevant build log. It seems to be including the `vl53l0x_platform.h` file alright. Thanks for your help!

```
1>  >>Building build/vl53l0x_platform.o
1>  arm-none-eabi-gcc -ffreestanding -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft -Og -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-move-loop-invariants -g3 -nostartfiles -I"conf" -I"inc" -IC:/Users/sohail/Documents/Cloud/STM32Cube_FW_F4_V1.7.0/Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -IC:/Users/sohail/Documents/Cloud/STM32Cube_FW_F4_V1.7.0/Drivers/CMSIS/Include -I"C:\Users\sohail\Documents\gcc-arm_launchpad_binaries\lib\gcc\arm-none-eabi\4.9.3\include" -I"C:\Users\sohail\Documents\gcc-arm_launchpad_binaries\arm-none-eabi\include\sys" -I"C:\Users\sohail\Documents\gcc-arm_launchpad_binaries\arm-none-eabi\include" -std=gnu11 -c -o build/vl53l0x_platform.o src/vl53l0x_platform.c
1>  In file included from inc/vl53l0x_api.h:33:0,
1>                   from inc/main.h:44,
1>                   from inc/vl53l0x_platform.h:34,
1>                   from src/vl53l0x_platform.c:37:
1>  inc/vl53l0x_api_strings.h:39:39: error: unknown type name 'VL53L0X_DEV'
1>   VL53L0X_Error VL53L0X_get_device_info(VL53L0X_DEV Dev, VL53L0X_DeviceInfo_t *pVL53L0X_DeviceInfo);
1>                                         ^
```

Comment: Check preprocessed code.

Comment: You should post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Totally guessing: some of the include included before `paltform.h` requires `VL53L0X_DEV` type?  If yes `platform.h` has to be on the top of those other headers includes.

Comment: You shouldn't try and typedef a pointer - You'll unnecessarily confuse yourself.

Comment: As suggested, switch the order of your includes: `platform.h` before `vl53l0x_api.h`

Comment: Or, if `vl53l0x_api.h` is included in `platform.h` you must define the struct before that include.

Comment: @LPs Thank you! There were a lot of 'circular' includes. The re-ordering helped. Could you post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments:

You probably have a circular dependencies on your headers.

Some of the include included before `platform.h` requires `VL53L0X_DEV` type? If yes `platform.h` has to be on the top of those other headers includes.

if `vl53l0x_api.h` is included in `platform.h` you must define the struct before that include.